# What is the best way to get an object which is not sure if there is or not in Django model

Tags: python, django, model

What is the best way to get an object which is not sure if there is or not.(in Django model)

I think there are three options.

One is to use `try` and `except` statement to process the exception.

Second is to use `objects.filter()` instead of `objects.get()` and check `query_set.count()`.

Third is to use `objects.count()` first and then use `objects.get()` if there is.

Answer (score 1):

You can **use [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) operation on a queryset** to your advantage to get the first object of the queryset if it exists and `None` otherwise.

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is
>   no matching object.

```
my_object = some_queryset.first() # return a object or 'None'
```

This will return the first object of the queryset if there are objects in the queryset. Otherwise, it returns `None`. It will automatically handle the case when objects do no exist without you needing to write `try-except`.

The above code is equivalent to writing:

```
try:
    my_object = some_queryset[0] # access the first element
except IndexError:
    my_object = None
```

**Note:** Here, we needed the object, so we are using `.first()`. If we needed to check only if the object exists, then we could have used [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** I think the best solution in this case, is use this third package
[django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying)
This packaged contains a lot of syntactic sugar for things like that.

With this package, you can use the function `get_object_or_None`, similar to
[get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

But, the real code behind this function is :

```
def get_object_or_None(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Uses get() to return an object or None if the object does not exist.
    klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
    arguments and keyword arguments are used in the get() query.
    Note: Like with get(), a MultipleObjectsReturned will be raised if more than one
    object is found.
    """
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
    try:
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

> Note: Don’t use this if all you want to do is determine if at least one result exists. It’s more efficient to use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists).